# data transfer between android app and asp.net C#

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, database, json

I want to send data from my android application to asp.net(c#).In C# page i will perform some database operations on the data received from android app and after that I will send back the results to my android application.

I don't have any idea of how to do this.Please anyone explain or give the link of some example.I have searched a lot but was not able to find the right answer.So please explain each step to follow or quote some links for examples.

Comment: I don't get the `send data to asp.net and then in C# page` part. You could use a service (wcf, for example) to perform your operations and send back the results to your android application. Does this satisfy your needs?

Comment: i have edited my question a little bit so please read it again and help me

Comment: @rupinder18: Are you saying that a service as suggested by Conrad does not satisfy your needs? What is this "data" you speak of? Is it some text like chat messages, or a ciphered byte stream? Can't you navigate to your asp page using the built in android web browser and send information "via http"?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at this, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is a framework for building service-oriented applications. Using WCF, you can send data as asynchronous messages from one service endpoint to another. A service endpoint can be part of a continuously available service hosted by IIS, or it can be a service hosted in an application.

Check out the link for more information, and google for `WCF`. I won't be able to explain everything in this answer, but I'll provide you the guidelines.

You can host your WCF service, and access it through HTTP (or whatever protocol you can use) . In your android, to make it easy you can use a library such as [KSOAP](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/). You can check some SO questions as well, [KSOAP ANDROID Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154919/ksoap-android-implementation) , [Getting Started with KSOAP on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587856/getting-started-with-ksoap-on-android?rq=1).

Now, now, if you're talking about opening a page in your android to process something, you can just post information to it, and get the response back and process it.

In this second case, I think you can use `HttpClient` and `HttpPost` classes, from 
`org.apache.http.client` package. Something in these lines:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.myaspnetstuff.com/process");

try {
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "1"));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

    //here you get your response and do whatever fits your needs.
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: tell me one thing is WCF the advanced version of webservice?

Comment: As far as I know, WCF is a replacement for all earlier web service technologies from Microsoft.